# How to call shared object function (loaded dynamically) from pointer in Go?

Tags: go, segmentation-fault, function-pointers, function-call, shared-objects

I try to call few shared object functions from Go. I don't want to write a C commented code to build a *CGO interface* for all functions.

I write my shared object like that:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void greet(char* name) {
    printf("Hello, %s!\n", name);
}
```

I compile it with: `gcc -shared -fPIC -o libgreet.so greet.c`.

My Go code to call the `greet` function:

```golang
package main

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -ldl
// #include <dlfcn.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"
import (
    "unsafe"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    so_name := C.CString("./libgreet.so")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(so_name))
    function_name := C.CString("greet")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(function_name))

    library := C.dlopen(so_name, C.RTLD_LAZY)
    defer C.dlclose(library)
    function := C.dlsym(library, function_name)

    greet := (*func(*C.char))(unsafe.Pointer(&function))

    fmt.Println("%p %p %p %p\n", greet, function, unsafe.Pointer(function), unsafe.Pointer(&function))
    (*greet)(C.CString("Bob"))
}
```

When i start the executable i get `SIGSEGV` errors.

I try to debug it with gdb and pointers printed seems to be good (that the same value than `x greet` in gdb). The segmentation fault come on the instruction `0x47dde4 <main.main+548>  call   r8` where `$r8` contains `0x10ec8348e5894855` (probably not a memory address).

Do you have any idea how i can fix this error ? There is a soluce to call shared object function in Go without a C code commented as the *CGO* syntax (i don't find any documentation to do it) ?